# Vue.js How to filtered out the ref by computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api

`Tag.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="tag">
    Tag: {{ tag }}<br>
    <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>

    # {{ posts.length }}<br>
    # {{ computedFilteredList.length }}<br>
    <br>
    ============# {{ computedFilteredList.length }} computedFilteredList=================
    <div v-if="computedFilteredList.length">
      <PostList :posts="computedFilteredList"/>
    </div>
    <div v-else><Spinner/></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import getPosts from "@/composables/getPosts";
import PostList from "@/components/PostList.vue";
import Spinner from "@/composables/Spinner.vue";
import {computed, ref} from "vue";
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";

export default {
  components: { Spinner, PostList },
  props: ['tag'],
  setup(){
    const { posts, error, load } = getPosts()
    load()

    const route = useRoute()
    console.log(posts.value.length)
    const computedFilteredList = computed(() => {
      return posts.value.filter((post) => {
        console.log(post)
        post.tags.includes(route.params.tag)
      })
    })
    return { posts, error, computedFilteredList }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

`PostList.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="post-list">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <SinglePost :post="post"/>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import SinglePost from "@/components/SinglePost.vue";
import {computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, onUpdated} from "vue";

export default {
  components: { SinglePost },
  props: ['posts'],
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

`getPost.js`

```
import {ref} from "vue";

const getPosts = () => {
  const posts = ref([])
  const error = ref(null)

  const load = async () => {
    try{
      // simulate delay
      // await new Promise(resolve => {
      //   setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      // })

      let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts')
      if(!data.ok){
        throw Error('no data available')
      }
      posts.value = await data.json()
    }
    catch(err){
      error.value = err.message
      console.log(error.value)
    }
  }
  return { posts, error, load }
}

export default getPosts
```

`db.json`

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "welcome to the new blog",
      "body": "rolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsum",
      "tags": [
        "webdev",
        "coding",
        "news"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "top 5 CSS tips",
      "body": "rolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsumrolrem iupsum",
      "tags": [
        "css",
        "webdev",
        "coding"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "test",
      "body": "test",
      "tags": [
        "rtet"
      ],
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "afdsa",
      "body": "asfads",
      "tags": [
        "fddsf",
        "asdf"
      ],
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:**
When I try create project with `> npm create vue@latest`
I got new problem.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PostList' before initialization at Tag.vue:26:26
```

**Warning:**
Failed to resolve component: PostList
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

**Problem:**
Computed property has no result.

**Question:**
Where am I wrong. I got this code from [Udemy class](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-web-apps-with-vuejs-firebase/learn/lecture/23585628#questions). Some of the student got the same question 2 years ago and no one answer to them.

Comment: You should focus your question to one problem only.  I have answered what seems to be the main problem of why the computed property is not working.  In regard to your other problems, you'll need to provide more details, and possibly post as new, separate questions.  `npm create vue@latest` could not possibly result in an Uncaught ReferenceError. The command is for scaffolding a brand new project and has nothing to do with existing projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback function should return a true/false value. This boolean tells the filter whether or not to include the object in the resulting filtered array.  If you don't return a boolean, the filter won't do any filtering at all.  In summary, **add a return statement to your filter**:

```js
const computedFilteredList = computed(() => {
  return posts.value.filter(post => {
    console.log(post)
    return post.tags.includes(route.params.tag) // return this result
  })
})
```

If you can write your filter function as one line, without function braces `{}`, the return value can be implied. This would involve removing the console log:

```js
const computedFilteredList = computed(() => {
  return posts.value.filter(post => post.tags.includes(route.params.tag))
})
```